# Incompatible type error when trying to assign a value to a linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

The struct is:

```
typedef AirportCode[4];
typedef struct node{
     AirportCode airport;
     struct node *next;
}Node;
```

Now what I am trying to do is this:

```
void insertFirst(AirportCode code, Node **listPtr){
     if (*listPtr == NULL)
      {
       (*listPtr)->airport = code;
       (*listPtr)->next = NULL;
      }
```

The error message I am getting is:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'AirportCode' from type 'char*'

Comment: The point of the if statement is, in case of a empty list, to create a node with the airport code inputed in the function

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef AirportCode[4];
```

This is not valid C++, is it supposed to be an array of `char`?

```
typedef char AirportCode[4];
```

A function parameter of array type decays to a pointer, so your `code` parameter has type `char*`, and you try to assign that to an array, which isn't allowed. You probably want to copy each character instead of trying to assign the whole array:

```
memcpy(*listPtr)->airport, code, sizeof(AirportCode));
```

It might be better to replace your `AirportCode` typedef with a class that represents an airport code:

```
struct AirportCode
{
    char code[4];
};
```

Doing this makes it a first-class type, not just a typedef for an array, which means argument passing and assignment works as expected:

```
(*listPtr)->airport = code;
```

Also, as a matter of style, you don't need a typedef for a strcut in C++, so you can just define `Node` as:

```
struct Node{
     AirportCode airport;
     Node* next;
};
```